# TypeScript does not check this type when assigning functions

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo {
  greet() {
    console.log('Hello World!')
  }
}

function fooFunction(this: Foo) {
  this.greet()
}

const func: () => void = fooFunction
func()
```

TypeScript does not have an issue with it (tried in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oHMBOBTXALgBQCUK6G0w8AdhPCLgHQjyZEDkAEriK9AHV42EABMAhBxIUAvqjmoAZgFcawAgEta0RYlir1WmkQIALDRABccRGTQYzFpjnzFpC6nQI6D10tABeAD5oADd4DVFAnT0DTVolA1JUIA)), even though it obviously crashes. Why is `(this: Foo) => void` assignable to `() => void`? Is it an oversight or is there some reasoning behind it?

Comment: If you changed `this: Foo` to `foo: Foo` it should behave. Assuming the compiler does something special given `this` is something inside of JS / TS. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oHMBOBTXALgBQCUK6G0w8AdhPCLgHQjyZEDkAEriK9AHV42EABMAhBxIUAvqjmoAZgFcawAgEta0RYlir1WmkV3wAXHERk0GU0xz5i0hdToEdBi6WgBeAHzQAG7wGqK+OnoGmrRKBqSoQA

Comment: @wonderflame its actually the opposite. `() => void` is a subtype of any function that returns void. Try assigning `(x: number) => void` to `() => void` and you'll get an error as expected.

Comment: This is the intended behavior. There's absolutely no reason why it shouldn't work. It's both idiomatic and sound.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I just posted code that crashes, how is that not a reason? `this` should be treated the same as regular arguments.